# Underscore Template not working with Backbone View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am not sure why my Underscore Template is not rendering.  I would like it to show 3 `select` drop down menus based on the data returned.

Here's a fiddle to my code.  Check the console for the data:  http://jsfiddle.net/f7v3g/

If you see the data returned you'll see the following structure

-models

--attributes

---dimensions

----object0

-----name (Will be the text label that appears next to the **first** drop down menu)

-----refinements (children of refinements should be the `option` tags)

----object1

-----name (Will be the text label that appears next to the **second** drop down menu)

-----refinements (children of refinements should be the `option` tags)

----object2

-----name (Will be the text label that appears next to the **third** drop down menu)

-----refinements (children of refinements should be the `option` tags)

Here's the Backbone JavaScript:

```
(function () {

    var DimensionsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: {
            dimensionName : 'undefined',
            refinements : 'undefined'
        }

    });

    var DimensionsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: DimensionsModel,

        url: 'http://jsonstub.com/calltestdata',

    });

    var setHeader = function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('JsonStub-User-Key', '0bb5822a-58f7-41cc-b8a7-17b4a30cd9d7');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('JsonStub-Project-Key', '9e508c89-b7ac-400d-b414-b7d0dd35a42a');
    };

    var DimensionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.js-container',

        initialize: function (options) {
            this.listenTo(this.model,'change', this.render);

            this.model.fetch({
                beforeSend: setHeader
            });

            console.log(this.model);

            return this;
        },

        render: function () {
            this.$el.html( this.template(this.model, 'dimensions-template') );
        },

        template: function (models, target) {
            var templateSelectors = _.template($('#'+target).html(),{
                dimensions: this.model
            });

            return templateSelectors;
        },

    });

    var myCollection = new DimensionsCollection();
    var myView = new DimensionsView({model: myCollection});

}());
```

Here is my HTML and Underscore template:

```
<div class="js-container">

    <script type="text/template" id="dimensions-template">
        <% _.each(dimensions, function(dimension,i){ %>

            <%- dimension.get('dimensionName') %> <select id="<%- dimension.get('dimensionName') %>">
                <option>Select</option>
                <%  _.each(dimension.get('refinements'), function(ref,x){ %>
                    <option data-refineurl='{
                        "refinementUrl": "<%- ref.refinementurl %>",
                        "nVal": "<%- ref.nval %>"
                    }'><%- ref.name %></option>
                <% }); %>
            </select>

        <% }); %>
    </script>

</div>
```

Edit: Spelling and example of data scructure.

Answer (score 1):

I see few mistake:

1) inside DimensionsView initialize, you should add a this.render call

2) inside template: function (models, target), you use this.models. but you pass models as first parameter ?

3) Did you add model to your collection somewhere? now you template will try to loop over them. So it need models to loop in the collection.

Comment: I updated the JS code and forked the fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/KT2B2/

I added a render call like you mentioned.

I also removed the template method and am setting that in the render method.

I thought that the model was already added to the collection wiht `model: DimensionsModel` in the DimensionsCollection section.  I am then passing that to the View when I instantiate a new version of the view.  Is that incorrect?  Thanks!

Comment: you passing it to the view, That fine. But you never add model to the modelCollection

Comment: I think I'm lost on this point.  I've updated the fiddle again with some comments as to where I thought I was adding the model to the collection and then passing the information to the view.  http://jsfiddle.net/KT2B2/

Comment: I meant that at the time render is called, the fetch is not done yet. could you try to add asyncLfalse in your fetch call

Comment: I have added `async: false` in the fiddle.  The fetch now looks like `dimensionCollection1.fetch({beforeSend: setHeader, async: false});`  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: It will work, but the best way is to automatically listenTo fetch event from you view. like that you do not have to block your code execution with async false. That would invole having your view listening on collection and collection listening on model... however I guess its a case by case choice ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49514/discussion-between-mdd-and-frederic-nault)